# Select Or'd Values of Multiple Rows (Bit Column)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this type of data in table

```
[3D445FC9-B765-40C1-AD45-F4ACE113153C]  1   1   0   0

[3D445FC9-B765-40C1-AD45-F4ACE113153C]  0   1   1   0
```

And I Want To Select

```
[3D445FC9-B765-40C1-AD45-F4ACE113153C]  1   1   1   0
```

Last Four Columns type is bit

Comment: your question is not mentioned well/

Answer (score 5):

Can you just use `MAX`?

```
SELECT id, MAX(col1), MAX(col2), MAX(col3), MAX(col4)
FROM MyTable 
group by id
```

As far as I know there is no bitwise aggregate function.

Comment: Last four column is in bit type and Max will not work on them

Comment: Thanks Abe it will Work after Cast bit to int